# Apache Zeppelin only listening on tcp6

Tags: tcp, apache-zeppelin, listen

Because I have just started with Zeppelin, I am a bit lost.

I installed via this page: http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/install.html

After installation Zeppelin appears to only listen on the tcp6 address on port 8080:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-164:~$ sudo netstat -lnp 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         
State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      1176/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      1203/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    
LISTEN      13719/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    
LISTEN      1176/sshd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           
1028/dhclient
```

I grepped all the installation files and didn't see where it was getting direction for the IP and port (other than template files in conf).

I was wondering if anyone had some more knowledge of Zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

- Remove ".template" from file name "zeppelin-site.xml.template"
- Change port in "zeppelin.server.port"
- Restart Zeppelin
- Go to localhost:new_port in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was fine.  It is listening on tcp4 even though it's not showing.  The issue was with my SSH port forwarding.